# How to display data using ArrayCollection (SQLite db) to a control that without dataProvider?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I know how to display data in a List control using dataProvider but what about control that don't have dataProvider e.g. TextInput, Label contorl?

I know how to display data in a List control using dataProvider but what about control that don't have dataProvider e.g. TextInput, Label contorl?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView"
            creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >

        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[


import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                private var db:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("users01.db");
                private var conn:SQLConnection;
                private var Stmt:SQLStatement;

                [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

                protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void          {
                    conn = new SQLConnection();
                    conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
                    conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                    conn.openAsync(db);
                }
                private function openHandler(event:SQLEvent):void {
                    log.text += "Database opened successfully";
                    conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
                    Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                    Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                    Stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserTable (" + 
                        "userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                        "userLevel," + 
                        "firstName TEXT," + "lastName TEXT)";
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult);
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                    Stmt.execute();
                }
                private function createResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                    log.text += "\nTable created";
                    conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult);
                    showResult();
                }
                private function errorHandler(event:SQLErrorEvent):void {
                    log.text += "\nError message: " +  event.error.message;
                    log.text += "\nDetails: " +  event.error.details;
                }
                private function insertResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                    log.text += "\nInsert completed";
                    showResult();
                }
                private function showResult():void  {
                    Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                    Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                    Stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM UserTable";
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                    Stmt.execute();
                }
                private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                    log.text += "\nSelect completed";
                    var result:SQLResult = Stmt.getResult();
                    listBox.dataProvider=new ArrayCollection(result.data);
                }
                protected function Save(event:MouseEvent):void          {
                    Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                    Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                    Stmt.text = "INSERT INTO UserTable (firstName, lastName, userLevel)" +
                        "VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :userLevel)";
                    Stmt.parameters[":firstName"] = firstName.text;
                    Stmt.parameters[":lastName"] = lastName.text;
                    Stmt.parameters[":userLevel"] = ID.text;
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                    Stmt.execute();
                }
                protected function Delete(event:MouseEvent):void    {

                    Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                    Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                    Stmt.text="DELETE FROM UserTable WHERE lastName = ?";
                    Stmt.parameters[0] = listBox.selectedItem.lastName;
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                    Stmt.execute();
                    trace("record deleted");
                }
                protected function Update(event:MouseEvent):void            {
                    Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                    Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                    Stmt.text = "UPDATE UserTable SET " +
                        "firstName=:firstName, " +
                        "lastName = :lastName " +
                        "WHERE userLevel = :userLevel2";
                    Stmt.parameters[":firstName"] = firstName.text;
                    Stmt.parameters[":lastName"] = lastName.text;
                    Stmt.parameters[":userLevel2"] = ID.text;
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                    Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                    Stmt.execute();
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>


        <s:Label text="FirstName" top="8" left="5"/>
        <s:TextInput id="firstName" left="-1" top="36" width="233" height="80"/>

        <s:Label text="LastName" top="0" left="248"/>
        <s:TextInput id="lastName" left="231" top="32" width="224" height="84"/>

        <s:Label text="ID" top="0" left="483"/>
        <s:TextInput id="ID" left="463" top="32" width="167" height="84"/>

        <s:Button left="10" top="151" width="121" height="54" label="Save" click="Save(event)"/>
        <s:Button left="139" top="151" width="146" height="54" label="Delete" click="Delete(event)" enabled="{listBox.selectedIndex != -1}"/>
        <s:Button left="293" top="151" width="147" height="54" label="Update" click="Update(event)"/>

        <s:List id="listBox" x="-1" y="265" width="641" height="167" itemRenderer="UserRenderer"></s:List>

        <s:TextArea id="log" x="0" bottom="4" width="100%" height="221"/>
    </s:View>
```

Try to use **{dp.ID}** and **{dp.getItemAt(0).ID}** on TextInput but nothing being display?

Thanks.

How to make **TextInput id="firstName"** able to display the SQL data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just assign the value to the TextInput object or else use another bindable string variable to bind to that you then assign in the method.  You should see a warning in during compilation that it won't be able to use bindings on that line when you do the getItemAt I believe.  dp.ID wouldn't make sense as the dataprovider is typed as an array collection and the collection itself has no ID property.  Bindings essentially work by creating an event dispatch any time the setter for a property is called, behind the scenes the mxml compiler will add a setter and getter for the property you mark bindable and automatically dispatch an event when the setter is called and the value has changed.  That event is captured and is set to whatever things you "bound" to it.  I copied your code below and modified:

EDIT (pasted your code from above again, two options from what I see below):

Option 1 based on what I originally saw:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView"
        creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var db:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("users01.db");
            private var conn:SQLConnection;
            private var Stmt:SQLStatement;

            [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void          {
                conn = new SQLConnection();
                conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
                conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                conn.openAsync(db);
            }
            private function openHandler(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "Database opened successfully";
                conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserTable (" + 
                    "userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "userLevel," + 
                    "firstName TEXT," + "lastName TEXT)";
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
            private function createResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nTable created";
                conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult);
                showResult();
            }
            private function errorHandler(event:SQLErrorEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nError message: " +  event.error.message;
                log.text += "\nDetails: " +  event.error.details;
            }
            private function insertResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nInsert completed";
                showResult();
            }
            private function showResult():void  {
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM UserTable";
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
            private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nSelect completed";
                var result:SQLResult = Stmt.getResult();
                listBox.dataProvider=new ArrayCollection(result.data);
                if(result.data.length>0)  //I ADDED THIS
                    firstName.text = result.data[0].firstName;  //I ADDED THIS
            }
            protected function Save(event:MouseEvent):void          {
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "INSERT INTO UserTable (firstName, lastName, userLevel)" +
                    "VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :userLevel)";
                Stmt.parameters[":firstName"] = firstName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":lastName"] = lastName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":userLevel"] = ID.text;
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
            protected function Delete(event:MouseEvent):void    {

                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text="DELETE FROM UserTable WHERE lastName = ?";
                Stmt.parameters[0] = listBox.selectedItem.lastName;
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
                trace("record deleted");
            }
            protected function Update(event:MouseEvent):void            {
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "UPDATE UserTable SET " +
                    "firstName=:firstName, " +
                    "lastName = :lastName " +
                    "WHERE userLevel = :userLevel2";
                Stmt.parameters[":firstName"] = firstName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":lastName"] = lastName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":userLevel2"] = ID.text;
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Label text="FirstName" top="8" left="5"/>
    <s:TextInput id="firstName" left="-1" top="36" width="233" height="80"/>

    <s:Label text="LastName" top="0" left="248"/>
    <s:TextInput id="lastName" left="231" top="32" width="224" height="84"/>

    <s:Label text="ID" top="0" left="483"/>
    <s:TextInput id="ID" left="463" top="32" width="167" height="84"/>

    <s:Button left="10" top="151" width="121" height="54" label="Save" click="Save(event)"/>
    <s:Button left="139" top="151" width="146" height="54" label="Delete" click="Delete(event)" enabled="{listBox.selectedIndex != -1}"/>
    <s:Button left="293" top="151" width="147" height="54" label="Update" click="Update(event)"/>

    <s:List id="listBox" x="-1" y="265" width="641" height="167" itemRenderer="UserRenderer"></s:List>

    <s:TextArea id="log" x="0" bottom="4" width="100%" height="221"/>
</s:View>
```

Option 2 (assuming that you want to bind based on the selectedItem in the list):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView"
        creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var db:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("users01.db");
            private var conn:SQLConnection;
            private var Stmt:SQLStatement;

            [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                conn = new SQLConnection();
                conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
                conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                conn.openAsync(db);
            }
            private function openHandler(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "Database opened successfully";
                conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserTable (" + 
                    "userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "userLevel," + 
                    "firstName TEXT," + "lastName TEXT)";
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
            private function createResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nTable created";
                conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult);
                showResult();
            }
            private function errorHandler(event:SQLErrorEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nError message: " +  event.error.message;
                log.text += "\nDetails: " +  event.error.details;
            }
            private function insertResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nInsert completed";
                showResult();
            }
            private function showResult():void  {
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM UserTable";
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
            private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
                log.text += "\nSelect completed";
                var result:SQLResult = Stmt.getResult();
                listBox.dataProvider=new ArrayCollection(result.data);
                listBox.selectedIndex = 0; //I ADDED THIS
            }
            protected function Save(event:MouseEvent):void          {
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "INSERT INTO UserTable (firstName, lastName, userLevel)" +
                    "VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :userLevel)";
                Stmt.parameters[":firstName"] = firstName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":lastName"] = lastName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":userLevel"] = ID.text;
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
            protected function Delete(event:MouseEvent):void    {

                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text="DELETE FROM UserTable WHERE lastName = ?";
                Stmt.parameters[0] = listBox.selectedItem.lastName;
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
                trace("record deleted");
            }
            protected function Update(event:MouseEvent):void            {
                Stmt = new SQLStatement();
                Stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                Stmt.text = "UPDATE UserTable SET " +
                    "firstName=:firstName, " +
                    "lastName = :lastName " +
                    "WHERE userLevel = :userLevel2";
                Stmt.parameters[":firstName"] = firstName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":lastName"] = lastName.text;
                Stmt.parameters[":userLevel2"] = ID.text;
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
                Stmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
                Stmt.execute();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- I ADDED STUFF HERE -->
    <s:Label text="FirstName" top="8" left="5" />
    <s:TextInput id="firstName" left="-1" top="36" width="233" height="80" text="@{listBox.selectedItem.firstName}" />

    <s:Label text="LastName" top="0" left="248"/>
    <s:TextInput id="lastName" left="231" top="32" width="224" height="84"/>

    <s:Label text="ID" top="0" left="483"/>
    <s:TextInput id="ID" left="463" top="32" width="167" height="84"/>

    <s:Button left="10" top="151" width="121" height="54" label="Save" click="Save(event)"/>
    <s:Button left="139" top="151" width="146" height="54" label="Delete" click="Delete(event)" enabled="{listBox.selectedIndex != -1}"/>
    <s:Button left="293" top="151" width="147" height="54" label="Update" click="Update(event)"/>

    <s:List id="listBox" x="-1" y="265" width="641" height="167" itemRenderer="UserRenderer"></s:List>

    <s:TextArea id="log" x="0" bottom="4" width="100%" height="221"/>
</s:View>
```

Comment: I get a RangeError: Index '0' specified is out of bounds. I even try using getItemAt(1) but still same error.

Comment: this means dp isn't yet populated.  getItemAt is zero indexed so if there is 1 item in the collection the item will be at index 0, so getItemAt(0) would be the correct way to retrieve the item, drop a debug breakpoint in your selectResult handler, I haven't used the SQL APIs much but you should probably have an event.result in there, I was assuming you were assigning dp = event.result somewhere above the code I wrote into that method.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: I just looked through the docs about SQLStatement and modified by answer above

Comment: after trying out for sometime, still can't get it working. Maybe if the whole code would be better. Please check the updated code. thanks for your help.

Comment: @jameslcs no problem, check my updates above based on the rest of your code, if you're still having problems please give the particular error or behavior your seeing

Comment: @jameslcs sorry if you saw that a couple of minutes ago I had some bad formatting that was breaking up the code, I fixed it now (and after having just been complaining about someone else doing the same on SO, doh!)

Comment: @shunhusain thank for the solution both solutions works! very good, btw the text="@{listBox.selectedItem.firstName}" has to be bind in order for SelectIndex to work, ['@' added ] and i move it from Label to TextInput. thanks again.